# Download maven2 repository for offline use

Tags: maven, repository, offline

We are developing offline due to limited internet resources and would like to run once every several months a whole grab of an external repository (e.g `repo1.maven.org/maven2` - Disk space isn't an issue).

Today I'm using a simple POM that contains a lot of common dependencies that we are using, I've set my local maven to use a mirror to proxy thru a local nexus repository to cache locally and this is how I'm grabbing for offline use - but that isn't very effective.

I'm now looking for a command line tool that allow me to run searches on maven repositories so that I can write a script that grab them all to my local nexus installation and would like to hear if there is any or if there is another way to achieve that.

Thanks

Comment: You can set up a private repository in your own network and configure this as a mirror for the maven central. You can use [nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype)

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is a goal in Maven dependency plugin called "`go-offline`"
So it allows to grab all the project dependencies and to store them in local `.m2` repo.

You can find more information [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html).

If you want to run Maven and tell it to behave like the network does not exist you can run it with "-o" option (offline mode). So that if there is no dependency installed locally, Maven won't even try to go to network and bring it - but will fail the build.

On the opposite, if you want to force Maven to check and bring new versions (otherwise they already should be in your repo), you can use "-U" option.

I'm not really sure I've got the point about general search-and-download use case. Usually people install Nexus or Artifactory once in a network so that each dependency will be downloaded only once. In local development machines people usually just work with filesystem and don't maintain tools like this.

Now if you want to copy the whole repository from internet (for copying it later to some other network or something) you can just use crawlers like [Apache Nutch for example](http://nutch.apache.org) or craft your own script that will recursively download all the files.

Comment: Going offline (as settings) doesn't serve at all the purpose. The use case is simple - We have internet connection once in while and during that time we would like to grab as much as jars (dependencies) as possible - The dependencies are NOT part of the project's POM but generic ones that we might need in the future - since we don't have internet we just want to fetch them all and not based on a specific project

Comment: Ok, now I've got it. Once I used to work in an environment that had a totally different network for development without any kind of internet access. So we also had to download the whole nexus repository. Then we just wrote a script that crawled over maven repository and downloaded everything. Repo1 exposes http api, so it should be easy: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Answer (score 0):

Not a whole solution (yet) but I'm using httrack to grab the whole content of `repo1.maven.org/maven2` - That is already better than nothing :)